# Reinstalling my Windows machine and wanting to preserve iTunes backups

Tags: iphone, itunes, windows, backup, data

Is there a way to preserve the backups from all my iDevices stored into the iTunes folder - photos, audio notes, SMS etc. and move them to the new Windows installation.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the iOS version of your devices, I suggest backing up to iCloud instead. If you have iOS 5 installed, find iCloud in Settings, select storage and backup, and backup all of your devices.

If you do not have enough room for all of your devices under iCloud or if they don't have iOS 5, you can follow [this](http://www.geekguides.co.uk/130/where-does-itunes-keep-its-iphone-backups/) guide to back them up.

Comment: What about the files from my old iDevices which are not on the new ones? Pictures from my 3GS which are not on my 4s?

Comment: Those will be included in the backup.